# How to stop auto-guessing of urls and redirect all Invalid urls to 404 in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a site `example.com`. When I try to load a URL `example.com\a` it will automatically redirect to `example.com\about-me` page and the same for other letters as well. Is there a way to redirect all the non existing URLs to 404?

Comment: WordPress does redirect invalid URLs to a 404 page by default though. If it's not doing it on your website then something else is causing this redirect-to-home behavior. Double check your .htaccess rules.

Comment: This is a WordPress issue, not `.htaccess`. Only WordPress knows you have a page with URL `/about-me` (that starts with an `a`) to which to redirect to. Check the HTTP response headers of the redirect response, do you see an `X-Redirect-By` header?

Comment: @cabrerahector "this redirect-to-home behavior" - it's not redirecting to "home", it's redirecting to a URL/page that starts with the stated letter!

Comment: Fair enough, however the point doesn't really change @MrWhite: stock WordPress redirects invalid URLs to a 404 page. The fact that WP is not behaving like this on OP's website seems to suggest that there are some configuration issues there.

Comment: Related question on WordPress SE: [Disable Wordpress URL auto complete](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/92103/disable-wordpress-url-auto-complete), another off-site link: [Stop WordPress Partial Match Redirection](https://www.intelliwolf.com/stop-wordpress-partial-match-redirection/) (intelliwolf.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found the solution!

Adding this to the function file solves the problem I am facing it's a new feature in WordPress 5.5+ version to auto-redirect to the nearest match URL if an incorrect URL is entered.

```
add_filter('do_redirect_guess_404_permalink','stop_redirect_guess');
function stop_redirect_guess() {
    return false;
}
```

For older version of WordPress

```
add_filter( 'redirect_canonical','stop_redirect_guess' );
function stop_redirect_guess( $url ) {
    if ( is_404() ) {
        return false;
    }
        return $url;
}
```

And just adding the below code to .htaccess file will redirect you to a 404 custom page you have made or your theme has.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Or you can add a link directly like(worked for me)

```
ErrorDocument 404 example.com/404
```

Comment: "it's a new feature in WordPress 5.5+" - Although the WordPress SE question I linked to above that appears to have the same issue is from 2013 and the blog article also discusses a solution for WordPress before 5.5.

Comment: Thanks a lot i am new to stack exchange so I missed this message and also the solution article you posted  i thought It was a recommendation by stack exchange it's self. I came to realise later that it was you who provided it thanks a lot once again

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress automaticly handles invalid url requests. If invalid urls not redirect to 404 page you should check your .htaccess file. If Wordpress can redirect default 404 page, you can edit your existing 404.php file or create new one. Here is redirect code for your 404.php file:

```
header("Location: your about-me page url");
```

Comment: So my local has a stock WordPress installation form WordPress.org behaving the same way as above.

Comment: I have also replaced htacess incase it was corrupted. And it's not just doing this for about-us if i write site.com\s it will redirect to site.com\services to services page if i write site.com\b it will redirect to site.com\blog to blogs page. Basically any nearest match to the entered url . But it will redirect to a 404 when i give a long url like site.com\rueysiiqrakhxj.